# Is there a way to automatically set an environment variable when an ELF binary begins execution?

Tags: linux, clang, elf, address-sanitizer, lld

I have a binary executable `mytest`, created with Clang and bfd/lld, and in order for it to work correctly I have to pass the environment variable `ASAN_OPTIONS="use_sigaltstack=1"` to it, but I want to avoid having to manually type that in every time I want to run the executable from the command line.

I could create a wrapper script, of course, but that adds more complexity.

Is there a way, when creating the binary, to attach the environment variable and its value to the binary so that it is automatically set when execution begins?

It is too late to set the environment variable in my code, because Asan reads the environment variable before my code starts running.

Comment: No, there's no such thing. Why not just set the environment variable in your `.profile`?

Comment: Another option changing the code, no? (Using `putenv`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html )

Comment: @tmrlvi The variable might need to be set before `main()` runs, since it's controlling a runtime library.

Comment: The answer to this question greatly depends on whether you ask specifically about `ASAN_OPTIONS` or arbitrary environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

First thing first: for Asan the recommended approach is to implement `__asan_default_options` (as explained in [Asan wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flags)).

In general, you could reset environment variable by calling `setenv`/`putenv` at program start. But this would not help if variable is used in initialization code (as is the case with Asan).

You could also provide a custom hacky implementation of `getenv` which would return desired value for `"ASAN_OPTIONS"` and forward to normal Glibc implementation (obtained via `dlsym`) otherwise. But that would not help with Asan either because it obtains environment variables by reading `/proc/self/environ`.

Yet another hacky approach is to `setenv` and then restart the executable via `exec` syscall. This may change program semantics so is not recommended. Asan uses this approach on OSX due to lack of better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to avoid having to manually type that in every time I want to run the executable from the command line.

One way to achieve this is to re-`execv` the binary if it finds that `ASAN_OPTIONS` is missing. That is: in `main` check whether `ASAN_OPTIONS` is set via `getenv`. If not, call `setenv(ASAN_OPTIONS, ...)` and `execv(argv[0], argv)`.

Beware: this makes the binary hard(er) to debug.